# Absolutely positioned image div overflowing content to its left

Tags: html, css

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyU5L/3/

I have a container (original size is 940px) div that's contained inside the body.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="container">

    <div class="div-content">
    </div>

</div>
 <div class="image-content">
           <img src=""/>
     </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I need that image div to be contained against the side of the window. Be positioned absolute right to the body.

When you resize, you'll the see the image go over the content. I want the image to take that content div into consideration and push the text left, not go over it. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, you are doing it wrong. If you need the image to be always on the right side of the content, then you need not use `position:absolute` and align it to top-right using `top:0 & right:0`. Instead simply use two divs, one for content and another for div and give proper widths. And use `float:left` to good use. Should be simple.

Comment: u can simply use content as float:left and image as float:right; and move image div to inside the container div...thats it.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/P2KQ6/

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/uyU5L/5/

```
.container {
    max-width: 340px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 100px;
}
.div-content {
    padding: 40px 15px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.image-content {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
.image-content img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
    .container {
        margin: 0 100px 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yKQFG/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use two divs one(let's call "content-wrapper") for holding content and another(image-wrapper) for holding div of image
2. for first put float:left , for second float:right
3. give proper width to both
4. ur done

Comment: That will keep the two divs inside their container, one to the left and one to the right, yes. It won't, however keep my image absolutely right (absolute: right) to the body (the browser window)